# Find / Rename command not catching the filenames I want it to find

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have these two files in my home directory -

```
hello_newest.txt
goodbye_newest.txt
```

I want to rename them so that the "newest" part of the filename is removed completely, so that they would recome `hello.txt` and `goodbye.txt`

This is the command I am running -

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec rename 's/newest//i' {} ";"
```

It doesnt throw an error or do anything to the files after I run this command.  I've checked out http://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm and it looks like it should be working based on some of those examples that are there.

I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I missing?

Comment: It seems to be working except that you need to include `_` in the matched string to be removed.

Comment: Even adding that, none of the files are renamed after running the command.  This on on RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it might be the version of Redhat we were on.  The command -

`rename _newest '' *`

Seems to accomplish the same goals.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Different Syntax. But worked for me :

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/_[^.]*//'`"; done
```

All the txt files are found using for loop and then the charecters after underscore is removed using sed.